# query to find the document with vId in mongodb compass

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
let js = {
"data":{
  "id":"123",
  "vrnt":[
      {"vID":1},
      {"vID":2}
    ]
   }
 }
```

i have to find vId in compass but unable to do so
compass query

```
{"data.vrnt.vID":1}
```

Comment: It's a valid query. Explain more. [play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0MG3-J-H-6A) You can check here

Comment: what happens to data in kafka queue if consumer takes time to process each data does all the data that was sent by producer is lost, could u ans this please

Comment: out of the topic. But, Kafka is durable. Slow consumer is not a problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.